# PIG-Hadoop - In PIG is there a way to Inner-Join with Reg-Ex

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have 2 files (messages, keys).  I want to pull out all the lines out 'messages' that include a word from 'keys'.

```
messages = LOAD 'my-messages.txt' as (message:chararray);
keys = LOAD 'keys.txt' as (key: chararray);
```

Now I know I can do an inner join between messages & keys, but that won't work in situations such as:

```
message = "hi there"
key = "hi"
```

I'm thinking of a UDF as a way to get around it:

```
DEFINE containsKey my.udf.Matches("path/keys.txt");
matches = FILTER messages BY containsKey(messages);
```

Then inside the UDF loop through all keys (yikes!)  Doesn't feel right...Not sure if my approach is right, so feel free to offer suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a use case where CROSS can be used. Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#CROSS

This might not be an optimal solution, sharing a feasible approach.

**Input :**

**Messages :**

```
hi there
He said "Hi, how are you doing ?"
HI there
Hello there
```

**Keys :**

```
hi
```

**Pig Script :**

```
messages = LOAD 'messages.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (message:chararray);
keys = LOAD 'keys.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (key:chararray);

crossed_data = CROSS messages, keys ;

filt_required_data = FILTER crossed_data BY LOWER(messages::message) MATCHES CONCAT('.*', LOWER(keys::key), '.*');

required_data =  FOREACH filt_required_data GENERATE messages::message AS message;

DUMP required_data;
```

**Output :**

```
(hi there)
(He said "Hi, how are you doing ?")
(HI there)
```

Comment: Thank you this certainly worked!!...one small-minor syntax issue around concat: concat(concat('.*',LOWER(keys::key)),'.*')

Comment: @hba: From Pig Version 0.13 we have support for variable arguments in CONCAT method. I think you are using an older version. In this case you have to use CONCAT method twice.